# Ensure a URI is valid

Tags: validation, url, go

I'm trying to ensure that URLs passed to my go program are valid. However, I can't seem to work out how to. I thought I could just feed it through `url.Parse`, but that doesn't seem to do the job.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    url, err := url.Parse("http:::/not.valid/a//a??a?b=&&c#hi")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("It's valid!", url.String())
}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/uhG4SsVfoW)

Is there anything along the lines of [filter_var](https://eval.in/190813) I can use?

Comment: beside the totally right advice below using 'url' as variable name beside using the url-package is no good idea :-)

Comment: @ABri I realised that when my program broke :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate URL with standard package in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480710/validate-url-with-standard-package-in-go)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check that your URL has a Scheme, Host, and/or a Path.

If you inspect the URL returned, you can see that the invalid part is inserted into the Opaque data section (so in a sense, it is valid).

```
url.URL{Scheme:"http", Opaque:"::/not.valid/a//a", Host:"", Path:"", RawQuery:"?a?b=&&c", Fragment:"hi"}
```

If you parse a URL and don't have a Scheme, Host and Path you can probably assume it's not valid. (though a host without a path is often OK, since it implies `/`, so you need to check for that)

```
u, err := url.Parse("http:::/not.valid/a//a??a?b=&&c#hi")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if u.Scheme == "" || u.Host == "" || u.Path == "" {
    log.Fatal("invalid URL")
}
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer when writing mine. +1

Comment: Ah, useful. That way I can force the scheme to always be HTTPS too.

Comment: You might want to exclude the `u.Path` check, otherwise a url such as `https://google.com` is going to be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

have a try of this package   [go validator](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator) and the IsURL func is what you want.(you can use regexp package as well)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const URL string = `^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\S+(:\S*)?@)?((([1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(\.(1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.([0-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(((([a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?-?_?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)\.)?)?(([a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?-?_?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.([a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,}))?)|localhost)(:(\d{1,5}))?((\/|\?|#)[^\s]*)?$`

func Matches(str, pattern string) bool {
    match, _ := regexp.MatchString(pattern, str)
    return match
}
func main() {
    u1 := "http:::/not.valid/a//a??a?b=&&c#hi"
    u2 := "http://golang.fastrl.com"
    func(us ...string) {
        for _, u := range us {
            fmt.Println(Matches(u, URL))
        }
    }(u1, u2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [url.Parse()](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) function will return an error mainly if `viaRequest` is true, meaning if the URL is assumed to have arrived via an HTTP request.
Which is not the case when you call `url.Parse()` directly: see the [source code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/url/url.go?s=8497:8544#L323).

```
if url, err = parse(u, false); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

And `func parse(rawurl string, viaRequest bool) (url *URL, err error) {` only returns `err` if `viaRequest` is true.

That is why you never see any error when using `url.Parse()` directly.

---

In that latter case, where no `err` is ever returned, you can check the fields of the [`URL` object](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) returned.
An empty `url.Scheme`, or an `url.Path` which isn't the one expected would indicate an error.