# Validate URL with standard package in GO

Tags: validation, go

Is there any function in a standard package in GO that allows to validate a URL?

I have not found anything on my initial search,
and I would prefer not to resort to regex checking.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Yep, [`url.ParseRequestURI`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseRequestURI) returns an error if the URL is not valid, not an absolute url, etc etc. [`url.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) returns valid on almost anything...

```
import "net/url"

...


u, err := url.ParseRequestURI("http://google.com/")
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```

The above example will not fail, but these will:

```
u, err := url.ParseRequestURI("http//google.com")

u, err := url.ParseRequestURI("google.com")

u, err := url.ParseRequestURI("/foo/bar")
```

Comment: Here is an example of [both of these returning junk](https://play.golang.org/p/-TFUkUdDlU)

Comment: @Xeoncross I'm pretty sure that's a valid URL

Comment: Looked [at the spec RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), you are right @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: did something change? relative URLs now pass. https://play.golang.org/p/7v5YF24DUP

Comment: `u, err := url.ParseRequestURI("/foo/bar")`

This passes with Go 1.15.

Comment: Somehow it is giving me "javascript:alert(0)" is a valid url...

Answer (score 48):

The accepted answer allows empty `http://` and  relative urls like `/foo/bar`.  If you want a stricter check, this will reject those:

```
import "net/url"

func IsUrl(str string) bool {
    u, err := url.Parse(str)
    return err == nil && u.Scheme != "" && u.Host != ""
}
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/JngFarWPF2-

Which came from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25747925/744298

Comment: alse need validate  if  "." in str when str not ip

Comment: "http://[::1]" and "http://[::1]:8080" considered valid urls with this.

Comment: @Balu Of course they are considered, because they are valid. ::1 is the equivalent of 127.0.0.1 as an IP V6. IP V6's are determined between "[" and  "]" in URLs. So there's not an issue here.

Answer (score 9):

This helped me understand how the standard library [url.Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) method works, hope it helps some of you as well. Notice that all these values never throw an error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    urls := []string{
        "https",
        "https://",
        "",
        "http://www",
        "http://www.dumpsters.com",
        "https://www.dumpsters.com:443",
        "/testing-path",
        "testing-path",
        "alskjff#?asf//dfas",
    }
    for _, u := range urls {
        val, err := url.Parse(u)
        scheme := val.Scheme
        host := val.Host
        hostname := val.Hostname()
        path := val.Path
        fmt.Println("val        : "+u+" : ", val)
        fmt.Println("error      : "+u+" : ", err)
        fmt.Println("scheme     : "+u+" : ", scheme)
        fmt.Println("host       : "+u+" : ", host)
        fmt.Println("hostname   : "+u+" : ", hostname)
        fmt.Println("path       : "+u+" : ", path)
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

The results

```
val        : https :  https
error      : https :  <nil>
scheme     : https :
host       : https :
hostname   : https :
path       : https :  https

val        : https:// :  https:
error      : https:// :  <nil>
scheme     : https:// :  https
host       : https:// :
hostname   : https:// :
path       : https:// :

val        :  :
error      :  :  <nil>
scheme     :  :
host       :  :
hostname   :  :
path       :  :

val        : http://www :  http://www
error      : http://www :  <nil>
scheme     : http://www :  http
host       : http://www :  www
hostname   : http://www :  www
path       : http://www :

val        : http://www.dumpsters.com :  http://www.dumpsters.com
error      : http://www.dumpsters.com :  <nil>
scheme     : http://www.dumpsters.com :  http
host       : http://www.dumpsters.com :  www.dumpsters.com
hostname   : http://www.dumpsters.com :  www.dumpsters.com
path       : http://www.dumpsters.com :

val        : https://www.dumpsters.com:443 :  https://www.dumpsters.com:443
error      : https://www.dumpsters.com:443 :  <nil>
scheme     : https://www.dumpsters.com:443 :  https
host       : https://www.dumpsters.com:443 :  www.dumpsters.com:443
hostname   : https://www.dumpsters.com:443 :  www.dumpsters.com
path       : https://www.dumpsters.com:443 :

val        : /testing-path :  /testing-path
error      : /testing-path :  <nil>
scheme     : /testing-path :
host       : /testing-path :
hostname   : /testing-path :
path       : /testing-path :  /testing-path

val        : testing-path :  testing-path
error      : testing-path :  <nil>
scheme     : testing-path :
host       : testing-path :
hostname   : testing-path :
path       : testing-path :  testing-path

val        : alskjff#?asf//dfas :  alskjff#?asf//dfas
error      : alskjff#?asf//dfas :  <nil>
scheme     : alskjff#?asf//dfas :
host       : alskjff#?asf//dfas :
hostname   : alskjff#?asf//dfas :
path       : alskjff#?asf//dfas :  alskjff
```

Comment: this makes me not to implement the built-in as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
func IsUrl(str string) bool {
    url, err := url.ParseRequestURI(str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Info(err.Error())
        return false
    }

    address := net.ParseIP(url.Host)
    log.Infow("url-info", "host", address)

    if address == nil {
        log.Infow("url-info", "host", url.Host)

        return  strings.Contains(url.Host, ".") 
    }

    return true
}
func Test_IsAllowUrl(t *testing.T) {
    assert.True(t, IsUrl("http://google.com"))
    assert.True(t, IsUrl("http://w.com/cn"))
    assert.True(t, IsUrl("http://192.158.0.1:90"))
    assert.False(t, IsUrl("http://w"))
    assert.False(t, IsUrl("fsw"))
    assert.False(t, IsUrl("http://192.158.1/1"))

}
```

the last "http:/192.158.1/1" not pass. may be should match all allow domains,but will be to complex
https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db